# android emulator api level 11 not starting properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've been created android emulator with api level 11

**consider a setting bellow**

> [image]

Then I am start emulator with Google SDK Manager. But android phone start in landscape  as following
screenshot

> [image]

But api level 10 setting change it not start in landscape.

Is this some kind of bug or some issue with configuration

Comment: try to use Bluestacks or GenyMotions for Testing. its accurate.

Comment: Thanks for comment i will try on Bluestacks and GenyMotions

Answer (score 0):

Use any one of these for android testing. its much faster than ordinary emulators.

http://www.genymotion.com/

http://www.bluestacks.com/

I prefer GenyMotions. :)

Comment: Is this some kind of bug or some issue with configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is because Honeycomb was a tablet only release
try to create tablet avd and set the orientation to landscape.